# Problem integrating MySQL + Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, tkinter

I need to get some data from an SQL Database using Python.

I usually do the following

```
import mysql.connector
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk

(...)

cursor.execute("SELECT  * FROM solicitudes WHERE (fechaentrada BETWEEN %s AND %s) ", solicitudes2)

w=cursor.fetchall()

print(w)
```

Which, as desired, prints:

```
[(1, None, 'HM', 'prueba1', 'prueba1', 'MP', None, None, datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), datetime.date(2020, 5, 1), 'Sin disp', None), (2, None, 'HCL', 'prueba1', 'prueba1', 'AD', None, None, datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), datetime.date(2020, 5, 1), 'Sin disp', None), (3, None, 'HCR', 'prueba2', 'prueba2', 'AD', None, None, datetime.date(2020, 1, 10), datetime.date(2020, 5, 1), 'TA+2', None)]
```

This time, however, I get this 'raw format' with that exact code:

```
[{'id': 1, 'fecharegistro': None, 'hotel': 'HM', 'agencia': 'prueba1', 'pax': 'prueba1', 'regimen': 'MP', 'DUIrooms': None, 'SGrooms': None, 'fechaentrada': datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), 'fechasalida': datetime.date(2020, 5, 1), 'Propuesta': 'Sin disp', 'Comentario': None}, {'id': 2, 'fecharegistro': None, 'hotel': 'HCL', 'agencia': 'prueba1', 'pax': 'prueba1', 'regimen': 'AD', 'DUIrooms': None, 'SGrooms': None, 'fechaentrada': datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), 'fechasalida': datetime.date(2020, 5, 1), 'Propuesta': 'Sin disp', 'Comentario': None}, {'id': 3, 'fecharegistro': None, 'hotel': 'HCR', 'agencia': 'prueba2', 'pax': 'prueba2', 'regimen': 'AD', 'DUIrooms': None, 'SGrooms': None, 'fechaentrada': datetime.date(2020, 1, 10), 'fechasalida': datetime.date(2020, 5, 1), 'Propuesta': 'TA+2', 'Comentario': None}]
```

If I try to `print(w[1][2])`, which usually would return `'HM'`, I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:/www/CursoPandas/Solicitudes/06septimointentoapp.py", line 146, in nueva_solicitud
    panoramica()
  File "c:/www/CursoPandas/Solicitudes/06septimointentoapp.py", line 379, in panoramica
    print(w[1][2])
KeyError: 1
```

The code is in a function named `panoramica()`, which is called by a function named `nueva_solicitud()`, that is called with a Tkinter button.

Any idea? I'd be grateful.

I've been programming for a week, please don't be too harsh if the error is obvious.

Comment: How do you create the `cursor` variable?  It seems like you initialize `cursor` as instance of `MySQLCursorDict` class.  Also what is the output of `print(type(cursor))`?

Comment: Damn, that was the problem. I was creating it as `cursor = database.cursor(buffered=True, dictionary=True)`, while it works with `cursor = database.cursor(buffered=True)`. That was so fast!!